# Angular: ngOnInit hook does not work in dynamically created component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having the following directive that adds dynamic component to ng-container

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appAddingDirective]'
})
export class AddingDirective {

    constructor(protected vc: ViewContainerRef) { }

    public addComponent(factory: ComponentFactory<any>, inputs: any): void {
        this.vc.clear();
        const ref: ComponentRef<any> = this.vc.createComponent(factory);
        Object.assign(ref.instance, inputs); // can't find more elegant way to assign inputs((
        ref.instance.ngOnInit(); // IMPORTANT: if I remove this call ngOnInit will not be called
    }
}
```

The directive is used in an obvious way.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-wrapper',
    template: `<ng-container appAddingDirective></ng-container>`
})
export class WrapperComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    @ViewChild(DynamicItemDirective)
    private dynamicItem: DynamicItemDirective;

    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // hope it doesn't matter how we get componentFactory
        this.dynamicItem.addComponent(componentFactory, {a: '123'});
    }
}
```

Finally in a component that is loaded dynamically I have

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dynamic',
    template: '<p>Dynamic load works {{ a }}</p>'
})
export class DynamicComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() a: string;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.a);
        debugger;
    }

}
```

Here are my questions.

1. If I remove `ref.instance.ngOnInit()` call in `AddingDirective`, I do not get in `ngOnInit` of `DynamicComponent` (`debugger` and `console.log` do not fire up). Do component lifecycle hooks work in a component that is created and attached dynamically? What is the best way to make these hooks work?
2. I don't see rendered string `Dynamic load works 123` still if I remove `{{ a }}` in template (`template: '<p>Dynamic load works</p>'`), `Dynamic load works` is rendered as it should. What is the reason and how can I fix that?
3. Is there a better way to assing inputs than doing `Object.assign(ref.instance, inputs)` as above?

**PS.** I'm using Angular 11

Comment: I think this answer pretty much covers it -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427104/when-is-oninit-event-triggered-for-a-dynamically-loaded-angular-component